# Add syntax highlighting for posts with the [greasemonkey], [userscripts], or [content-script] tags

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

*Greasemonkey scripts*,  *userscripts* (as tagged on Stack Overflow), and *content-scripts* all run, and are implemented in, javascript.

Yet questions tagged with [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey), [userscripts](/questions/tagged/userscripts), or [content-script](/questions/tagged/content-script) show as plain gray unless:

1. They are also tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) -- which isn't always necessary or appropriate.
2. The poster uses the `<!-- language: lang-js -->` hint -- which I have yet to see someone besides myself do on those tags.

Please apply JavaScript syntax highlighting, by default, to questions tagged: [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey), [userscripts](/questions/tagged/userscripts), or [content-script](/questions/tagged/content-script).

Comment: They should be tagged with [tag:javascript] anyways, just retag them. (And what if I want to implement it in CoffeeScript? It's quite possible.)

Comment: @minitech: No, they should not all be tagged as javascript, as javascript often isn't a relevant part of the question.  But the code would  still benefit from highlighting,  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324/331508), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3937000/331508). ... Your CoffeScript argument is a red herring.  Out of 1623 applicable questions, exactly **two** are also tagged [CoffeScript]. Neither is harmed by JS syntax, and the prettify hints are still available if they were.

Comment: Sure, it's a relevant part of the question. They are written in JavaScript. I don't see how it's possible to get more relevant than that.

Comment: @minitech, your questions are written in English, so go tag all of them with that.  By your logic, you should.

Comment: Okay, the whole "by your logic" hyperbole is fun sometimes, but I'm just going to leave now.